# Do you need to use IPN with express checkout to confirm PayPal payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

When I use the Checkout express API calls do I need to have an IPN listener to confirm payment?

Some places give the idea that once I receive a response from DoExpressCheckoutPayment the payment has gone through and I can take action - update the database etc.
Some posts here http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?72304-Paypal-IPN-and-Express-Checkout suggests that IPN is old or outdated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use either or, or you could use both.  The IPN will will update your system if the buyer pays with an echeck once it clears, just as it will update your system of refunds and chargebacks.  The respone from the Express Checkout API call wont do this.  You would have to check manually.

Comment: Thanks, so some payments are not instant and you will have to use IPN if want automatic notifications of **all** payments.

Comment: Correct.  The only payments that will be instant are those that the buyer is funding with their PayPal balance or a credit card.  If the buyer only has a bank account associated with their PayPal account, the transfer wont be instant.  You would have to wait for the eCheck to clear before you receive the funds.

Comment: Thanks, the PayPal documentation is a little confusing and not really clear on this point, and the few things I could find on the internet weren't much better.